Why is $E(X|Y=y)$ is a function of $Y$?
This is a question that was asked in our lecture (about probability and expected values) last week and I am struggling to understand it :

Why is $E(X|Y=y)$ is a function of $Y$?
Why is $P(X|Y=y)$ is a function of $X$?

The first question really confuses me because I would have thought that the expected value of x given y should be a function of X.
I tried to answer this using first principles . Here is my reasoning:
1. Conditional Expectation $E(X|Y=y)$:
The conditional expectation $E(X|Y=y)$:
$$E(X|Y=y) = \int x f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx$$
Where $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is the conditional probability density function of $X$ given $Y=y$.
Seeing that the variable of integration is $x$, the final answer will be in terms of $y$.
2. Conditional Probability P(X|Y=y):
The conditional probability P(X|Y=y) is defined:
$$P(X|Y=y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
Where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$, and $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal probability density function of $Y$.
In this case, $y$ is treated as a fixed value, and the result varies with different values of $x$.
Therefore, $P(X|Y=y)$ is a function of $x$, not $y$.
Is it correct what I have written?

First bullet point: it is not. It is a function of $y$. Hint: Doob-Dynkin lemma. That function surely depends on $X$ and $Y,.$ Second point: ditto.

It seems like $X$ means some different in the two questions. $E(X)$ means $X$ is a random variable, $P(X)$ means $x$ is an event.

This question is a duplicate of understanding the conditional probability of random variables for gaussian cases.

@ThomasAndrews on the other hand, OP's idiosyncratic notation $$P(X|Y=y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$ indicates that the LHS is supposed to be the conditional density. To OP: that is obviously a function of both, $x$ and $y,.$

Thank you everyone ... what I meant in the first question about $E(X|Y=y)$ ... I guess when you finish integrating it, the final answer is only in terms of $y$?

Sounds right. That notation is confusing a lot of people. Here is another post I wrote to help some one.

Thank you! I think this clarifies things a lot!

In your first formula, it´s obvious that the answer will only depend on $y$, becuase you are integrating respect to $x$ and this variable disappear.
In your second formula, it will depend on both variables $x$ and $y$.
But, you can see it in this other way too... the conditional expected value $E(X|Y)$ is a projection of the random variable $X$ onto the space of functions $\sigma(Y)$-measurables, so it "has" to depend on $Y$. The conditional probability $P(\lbrace X\in A \rbrace|Y)$ will depend on the set $A$. When you write $P(X|Y)$ you are writing the special case $P(\lbrace X\in \lbrace x \rbrace \rbrace|Y)$ that you can write as $P(\lbrace X=x \rbrace|Y)$ or simply $P(X|Y)$

thanks jose! :)

To start with, think about what the unconditional notations mean. $P_X(x)$ is "the probability distribution of the random variable $X$", which of course takes different values at different choices of the input $x$. If we're looking at die rolls, for example, you can ask about "the probability the die rolls a 1" or "the probability the die rolls a 6" - or generally, "the probability the die rolls an $x$". Clearly, this is a function of $x$.
Meanwhile, $E(X)$ is "the expected value of the random variable $X$", which means you are looking at something across all of the possible values of $x$, so of course you're going to get a single number rather than a function of $x$, and it doesn't make sense to ask about "the expected value of the die roll that is 6". You've integrated or summed out the variable $x$ and you're left with a value.
When you have joint random variables $X$ and $Y$, then, conditioning on the event $Y = y$ is just asking to spit out those single-variable results for $X$ when the value of $Y$ is known. Let's look at what happens to them:

$f_{X | Y = y}(x) = P(X = x | Y = y)$ is "the probability that $X$ has the value $x$, given that $Y$ has the value $y$". If $Y$ controls the number of sides on the die and $X$ is the roll, then we're asking "If I pull a die with 4 sides, what's the probability that I roll a 3?", "If I pull a die with $y$ sides, what's the probability of rolling $x$?". This is a function of both $x$ and $y$.

$E(X | Y = y)$ is "the expected value of $X$, given that $Y$ has the value $y$". So it's "If I pull the 6-sided die, what's the average I will roll on it?". Once the die has been taken from the bag, that average roll is completely determined by which one it is. "Given the die has $y$ sides, what is the average roll?" is clearly just a function of $y$.


You can flip the conditionals, and that changes what the question is - "Given that I rolled a 3 on the die, what is the probability that I pulled the 10-sided die?" is $P(Y = 10 | X = 3)$. The expectation $E(Y | X = 3)$ is a bit weirder to interpret, but it's something like "Given that I rolled a 3 on the die, what's the expected number of sides on the die?" (which equates to something like "If I repeat the process lots of times and only consider the times that I roll a 3, what's the average number of sides on the dice that I pulled out?")

Generally, X and Y will be random variables on a probability space ($\Omega,\mathcal{F},P$) with distributions $P_X$ and $P_Y$ respectively, which might be discrete or continuous. Note that conditioning on a continuous random variable is not the same as conditioning on the event {Y = y} as in the discrete case.
Let $\sigma(Y)$ be the S-algebra generated by Y on $\Omega$. The conditional expectation of X given Y, denoted by E(X|Y), is then given by any $\sigma$(Y)-measurable random variable Z with the property
$\hspace{20pt}\int_AZdP = \int_AXdP,\hspace{10pt}$ for any A $\in \sigma(Y)$
By the Doob-Dynkin lemma, there exists a function $\phi$ (uniquely defined up to a $P_Y$ null set) such that
$\hspace{20pt}E(X|Y)=\phi(Y)$
So we get E(X|Y=y) = $\phi(y)$, which is the answer to the first question.
The second question makes no sense in the form in which it is written. As has already been noted, the probability of P($X\in A|Y=y$) depends on A (and also on y and the distribution of X).
By writing P($X\in A|Y$) = E($\mathbf{I}_A$|Y), the Doob-Dynkin lemma again implies the existence of a function $\psi_A$ with the property P($X\in A|Y=y)= \psi_A(y)$. The issue is whether, given y, the mapping $A\to\psi_A(y)$ defines a probability distribution on ($\Omega,\mathcal{F}$).
If X and Y are discretely distributed with $P(X=x_i,Y=y_j) = p_{ij}$, then the conditional distribution is given by
$\hspace{20pt}\psi_A(y)=P(X\in A|Y=y_j) = \sum_{x_i\in A}\frac{p_{ij}}{p_{.j}},\hspace{5pt}$ where $p_{.j}$ denotes the marginal probability $p_{.j}=\sum_ip_{ij}$.
In particular is $P(X=x_i|Y=y_j) = \frac{p_{ij}}{p_{.j}}$.
If X and Y are continuously distributed with joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and marginal density $f_Y(y)$, then
$\hspace{20pt}\psi_A(y)=P(X\in A|Y=y) = \int_Af_{X|Y}(x,y)dx$,
with the conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$
But this is not the conditional probability P(X=x|Y=y).

Without going into technical details:
Conditional PMFs $P(X=x|Y=y)=:p(x|y)$ are clearly functions of both $x$ and $y$. Conditional expectations
$$E(X|Y=y)=\sum_{x} x p(x|y)$$
or for continuous RVs,
$$E(X|Y=y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x|y)dx=:g(y)$$
are functions of $y$ since the values of $x$ are "integrated out".
Examples are good to get used to things. If $U\sim \mathcal{U}(0, x)$ given $X=x$ where $X\sim \mathcal{Exp}(\lambda)$, what is $E(U|X=x)$? What is it a function of?
